# nextjs env not exposed to client

Tags: node.js, next.js, dockerfile

I use Next js 12.1 and I define some env in .env.local everything is fine in local but when I deploy in the server I realize environment variables that I define in server are undefined. when I log the env, it is undefined in the browser and is work in the server terminal.
here is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
  compiler: { styledComponents: true },
  env: {
     NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps

ENV http_proxy=http://fodev.org:8118
ENV https_proxy=http://fodev.org:8118

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
RUN npm install --force

# If using yarn with a `yarn.lock` comment out above and use below instead
# COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# If using yarn comment out above and use below instead
# RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

and this is one of my components name Footer

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const Footer = () => {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COMPANY_NAME );
  return (
    <footer
      className="md:px-10 lg:p-14 text-gray-600 relative flex flex-wrap justify-center mx-auto "
      style={{ background: "var(--gray)" }}
      dir="rtl"
    >
     <div>{process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COMPANY_NAME || "CmpName"}{" "}</div>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

browser console
[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbkON.png)

and server logs
[Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PETHJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update your question with example how you use this env.

From docs:

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because of the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix. This inlining occurs at build time, so your various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is built.

Read this page https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

there is difference when you use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID` or `const env = process.env` and then `env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID`

Comment: IDK whats the difference between them but i use process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID

Comment: When you use that it is replaced in build time, so you must define this env on next build and it will be no longer env variable it will be replaced with value.

Comment: I defined them in server i can access them in server side. for example i log one of them in component and it returned value in server terminal but in chrome console it returned undefined

Comment: sorry, maybe it is confusing. but it definitely same here

Comment: edited question, and add more details